# Blending Scene World Lights with Scene Lights

Tags: lighting, world

How to control blending between  Scene  World Lights and Scene Lights?

I would like to have  more control over the render , as the current render is a bit washed out.

Under Combined pass , could't find any option for blending.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mix your current *Background* node with another one through a *Mix Shader*, and use an *Input > Light Path > Is Camera Ray* as factor, now the first *Background* node will be the one affecting the light, the second one will still be the one seen as background:

[image]